# Confused by a boost spirit / phoenix / C++11 interaction

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix

I've tried to reduce this problem as far as I can.

If I uncomment `void initialize()`, then this code compiles. If I leave it commented out, then it doesn't build.

The only way I've found to fix this problem is to build in C++03 mode with `boost::shared_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`.

I've attempted with the stock clang compiler on OS X Lion (with libc++) and the following compilers on CentOS 6.4 x64:

```
/opt/llvm/3.2/bin/clang++ -gcc-toolchain /opt/gcc/4.7.2 -std=gnu++11 foo.cc -I/opt/boost/1.53.0/include -DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3 -DBOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT -DBOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
/opt/llvm/3.1/bin/clang++ -gcc-toolchain /opt/gcc/4.7.2 -std=gnu++11 foo.cc -I/opt/boost/1.53.0/include -DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3 -DBOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT -DBOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
/opt/llvm/3.0/bin/clang++ -gcc-toolchain /opt/gcc/4.7.2 -std=gnu++11 foo.cc -I/opt/boost/1.53.0/include -DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3 -DBOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT -DBOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
/opt/gcc/4.7.2/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11 foo.cc -I/opt/boost/1.53.0/include -DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3 -DBOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT -DBOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
/opt/gcc/4.7.1/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11 foo.cc -I/opt/boost/1.53.0/include -DBOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3 -DBOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT -DBOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
```

As usual, the compiler output from spirit is quite verbose, so I've included it as a gist:

- [Clang 3.2](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63bab7cee511c6d62fa2)
- [GCC 4.7.2](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6b75ec3504d90b87d845)

### The Code Follows...

```
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <memory>

class Object {
    public:
        void initialize(std::vector<int>) {
        }

        //void initialize() {
        //}
};

int main() {
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<std::string::iterator, int()> integer;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<std::string::iterator, std::shared_ptr<Object>()> object;

    using boost::phoenix::bind;
    using boost::spirit::_val;
    using boost::spirit::_1;

    object  
        = (*integer) [bind(&Object::initialize, *_val, _1)];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
```

Fixes it for me. And change `*val` to just `val` because phoenix will know how to bind the member function to it.

---

**UPDATE** As @llonesmiz hinted, this turns out to be related to ADL indeed. Though the relation is highly subtle.

- Somewhere along the way, the presence of `std::vector<>` in the *type* of the member-function-pointer is making ADL search the std namespace and finding `std::bind`, instead of `phoenix::bind`.
- Somehow, when you pass `val`, instead of `*val`, the compiler selects the phoenix `bind` as a better match.
- You can see that when you have a member function that takes, say, an `int` (instead of a type from the `std` namespace), the problem disappears, and phoenix bind is always selected.

You can see the above observations by inspecting the output of **[this minimal test program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=192b0963111dd0b39b47e18b935f3ddd-288888228249e7ca71581405a7791187)** that dumps the typeids of various bind expressions (and runs them through `c++filt`)

---

- See it live with GCC on **[http://liveworkspace.org/code/idDtv$0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/idDtv%240)**
- **Update** Clang seems to like it only with `boost::shared_ptr` instead: **[http://liveworkspace.org/code/idDtv$3](http://liveworkspace.org/code/idDtv%243)**. I can only assume this is due to libc++ differences (?)

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <memory>

class Object {
    public:
        void initialize(std::vector<int>) {
        }
};

int main() {
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<std::string::iterator, int()> integer;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<std::string::iterator, std::shared_ptr<Object>()> object;

    using boost::phoenix::bind;
    using boost::spirit::_val;
    using boost::spirit::_1;

    object  
        = (*integer) [bind(&Object::initialize, _val, _1)];
}
```

Comment: So. A few thoughts, I do have the Use_V3 defined. I just do it on the command line. Secondly, Clang on CentOS was using libstdc++ 4.7.2 as the C++ Library, so the implementation of std::shared_ptr should be identical between those compilers. That may not be the case on liveworkspace though, and I'll do some checking on my end. Thirdly, even if boost::phoenix::bind includes some code to automatically unpack the shared_ptr, shouldn't it work with it? _I'm also doing some more work on looking through you answer. I'll give a followup in a few more minutes_.

Comment: Yeah. So it looks like you're correct that removing the dereference operator almost fixes the issue. boost::shared_ptr works for both clang and gcc. libstdc++ 4.7.2's std::shared_ptr works only under gcc. I am still confused why it fails if I tell the code to dereference the shared_ptr.

Comment: @sharth Seems to be something related to ADL. [This](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1o2Gem$2) seems to work.

Comment: Okay. Here's why those overloads aren't being found. GCC declares it to be whatever compiler it actually is using the `__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__` macros. Clang lies and says it's something like 4.2.1. Boost, then goes in and says that libstdc++ 4.2.1 didn't have std::shared_ptr, so it doesn't include the overloads.

Comment: @llonesmiz I have indeed confirmed that it is in fact the `std::vector<>` parameter that pulls `std::bind` into associated ADL namespaces. I've updated the answer with some of my Sherlock-work trying to debug ADL lookup. Does anyone know a better way to 'debug' ADL/overload resolution?

Comment: @sehe Thanks for going the extra mile. No idea about another way to debug this, I just saw  that the first line in the g++ error output contained `std::Bind`.